# How to initialize a Composer project in Git Bash?

Tags: git, composer-php, git-bash

I am trying to initialize a composer project for the first time via Git Bash. But when I run the command "composer init" in the desired directory I get the following error:

> [RuntimeException]
> You have to run this command in interactive mode, or specify at least some data using --name, --require, etc.

[image: Screenshot from error in Git Bash]

In the Windows command line it does work but as Git Bash is my main command line I would like to do it through there. Does anybody have an idea how to fix this problem? I've also tried to initialize a project with npm which worked fine.

Comment: Where is `composer.exe` located? Have you tried with a leading `./`? e.g. `./composer init`

Comment: I can't find a file composer.exe, only the setup. When I do "composer init ." I get the following error: [Symfony\Component\Console\Exception\RuntimeException]
  Too many arguments, expected arguments "command". After that are the same arguments I got with the previous error.

Comment: I ran into the same problem and I have found a solution. Download the newest version of Git for Windows from https://gitforwindows.org install & run. Now composer init interactive mode is working.

Comment: I've done what you said. I still have the same error. Did you require or do anything else?

Answer (score 0):

As a workaround, I can `composer init` through Visual Studio terminal, even if it fails within Git Bash.